# i'm confusing on power of x in modular equation..

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

[image]

From question 1, i thought that fermat's little theorem.
a^p≡a ≡b^p ≡ b   (mod p )

and because (a,p)=1=(b,p) , (a,p^2)=1=(b,p^2),
a^(p^2)≡a≡b≡b^(p^2) mod p^2
but how can we know that a^p≡b^p mod p^2 ???

from question 2, it is alike using chinese theorem. 
but is chinese theorem used in the same unknown..?? 
for example, x≡a mod m , x≡b mod n     => x=c mod mn (unique, m,n are co prime.)

but in this question, .. i don't know well i think that the x, and y are not same unknown and also there can not be exist.. when x^≡a ... ( in chinese theorem, x was not quadratic..)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737541/numbertheory-the-existence-question?noredirect=1#comment3545930_1737541  .  The fact that $x,y$ are defined by quadratic relations is not relevant.  Once you have them, you can just invoke the CRT to "lift" the congruences to $mn$.

Comment: Hint: Let $b^2\equiv a\pmod{m}$ and $c^2\equiv a\pmod{n}$. Use the CRT to produce $x$ which is congruent to $b$ modulo $m$ and to $c$ modulo $n$.

Comment: A numerical example:  $3^2\equiv -1 \pmod 5$.  $5^2\equiv -1 \pmod {13}$.  By the CRT we should be able to find $z\pmod {65}$ with $z\equiv 3\pmod 5$ and $z\equiv 5 \pmod {13}$.  Indeed, $z\equiv 18 \pmod {65}$ does the job.  Easy to check that $18^2\equiv -1 \pmod {65}$.

Comment: Oh .... i finally understood what you mean thank you so much

Comment: Z=x modm  z=y modn crt-exist -> z^2=a modm z^2=a modn  -> by m n are co prime, z^2=a.mod.mn

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).